# Is this code segment legal in C?

Tags: c

function wait() is declared in another function. Is it legal?

```
void panic(const int reason, const char *strg) 
{
int ErrNo;
struct machine_attributes mach;
int ret, docstat, cnt;
pid_t pid, wait(int *), setsid(void); 
    ......
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Functions in C can't be defined inside of other functions, though some compiler extensions allow for it.

Comment: @templatetypedef: No, but they can be declared inside of other functions.

Comment: @Charles Bailey- Ah, forgot about that.  Isn't that forward-declaration scoped just to the function in which the declaration appears, though?  Kinda like a local struct?  This is yet another C(++) edge case I know nothing about.

Comment: The declaration is scoped but it allows you to call the declared function from inside the function where the declaration appears.

Comment: Can two functions be called with comma seperated ? Like `wait(int*),setsid(void);`. And one more thing, if we are calling a function you should pass a parameter by value, not just the type as in `wait( int*)`.

Comment: @Mahesh They aren't calls, they're declarations.

Comment: @Jim Balter Can even function declarations be comma seperated ? I don't that.

Comment: @Mahesh - it's not the case in this question, but yes, two functions can be called comma-separated.

Comment: @Mahesh function declarations are no different from other declarations that can be comma separated -- why shouldn't they be? Anyway, yes they can, yes this is legal C code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, so long as this declaration matches the actual definition of the function.

```
pid_t pid, wait(int *), setsid(void);
```

This declares three entities: a `pid_t` named `pid`, a function (taking `int*` and returning `pid_t`) named `wait` and a function (taking no parameters and returning `pid_t`) named `setsid`.

The declaration of `pid` is also a definition.

Comment: It would be appreciated if the person who wrongly downrated this correct answer would come out of the shadows, explain themselves, and remove their downrate.

Comment: The major problem I see in SO is most of the down voters don't care to give reasons while down voting. They should come out explaining the reasons which will help every one in understanding and learn from mistakes. Probably it's the time to post a wiki post on this issue !!

Comment: The declaration is in fact known to match the definition in this case, so the answer is "yes", but Charles's point is well taken for the general case. It should be added that this is bad practice -- use header files, not local declarations for external symbols.

Comment: @Mahesh It might be a good idea for SO to impose a far heavier rep penalty on a downrate that isn't accompanied by a comment.

Comment: @Jim Balter - I am about to post this on wiki.

Comment: +1 Pretty interesting that this is possible. Pretty scary, too, but mostly interesting :D

Comment: @Jim: It could be useful; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal C, and it could be useful in rare cases, for instance if you have a plain C (non-POSIX-oriented) source file that uses `wait` with `static` linkage for a function of its own, and suddenly realize you need to call the POSIX `wait` from a function in that file. By scoping the declaration in the function that calls it, you avoid conflicting with the file-scope `static` definition of `wait`.

Note that `pid_t` may be obtained from other headers that do not declare `wait` (or any functions), but in other cases you might not be able to use a trick like this due to missing types.

And yes, some may call this a horrible hack/abuse of the language. :-)